# Inconsistency in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Mathematica finds no roots for

```
Solve[-1==Sqrt[x]*Abs[a],x]
```

but it does find a root for

```
Solve[-1/Abs[a]==Sqrt[x],x]
```

which seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Using the option `MaxExtraConditions -> All` gives some insight.

Comment: `Solve[-1 == Sqrt[x] Abs[a], x, Reals]` works.

Comment: May be I do not see something, but I cannot understand, how it can work?  `Sqrt[x]` is always non-negative and so is `Abs[a]`. Did I miss something?

Comment: My question is why does it give a solution in the second case?

Comment: I found an even worse example

    Solve[-Abs[a]==Sqrt[x]*Abs[a],x]

gives the solution x=1.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Try the option I suggested.  The solution is returned with the condition that `Abs[a] < 0`.  That of course can never be true.  But `Solve` doesn't seem to know that.  It treats `Abs[a]` as it would any symbol or any expression free of `x`. We can also try this: `Solve[-1/Abs[a] == Sqrt[x] && Abs[a] > 0, x]`.  There will be no solutions.  The confusing thing is of course that despite all this, Mathematica does see that there are no solutions when giving the equation in the first form.  Maybe it automatically selects a different method for the first case and that method ...

Comment: ... does know that `Abs[a] >= 0` for any `a`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a full answer, but hopefully it will shine some light on what is happening.

To recap, we want to solve the equation

```
eq1 = -1 == Sqrt[x] Abs[a]
```

which can also be written in the equivalent form

```
eq2 = -1/Abs[a] == Sqrt[x]
```

There is no solution of this because `-1/Abs[a]` is always negative and `Sqrt[x]` is never negative.

`Solve` gets this right for `eq1` but not for `eq2`.

`Solve` usually gives generic solutions (see documentation, under Details) which may not be valid for all values of the parameters (here `a`).  However, we can ask it to generate (some or all) conditions under which the solution is valid.

```
Solve[eq1, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]

{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/Abs[a]^2, Abs[a] < 0]}}


sol = Solve[eq2, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]

{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/Abs[a]^2, Abs[a] < 0]}}
```

As you see, in both cases the solution is valid only under the condition that `Abs[a] < 0`.  Which is of course never true.  But in the case of `eq2`, Mathematica doesn't go all the way to find that out.

So this is really just a freak example of what "generic solution" can mean.  In some cases it's not valid for *any* values of the parameters.  But to "see" (compute) this, it requires extra work, which isn't always done automatically. `Solve` treats `Abs[a]` as any quantity and doesn't attempt to solve for the condition, even though it can.

```
Reduce[Abs[a] < 0, a]
(* False *)
```

We can instruct it to do this explicitly using [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html):

```
Refine[sol]

During evaluation of In[]: Refine::fas: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False.

(* {{x -> Undefined}} *)
```

Or like this

```
Reduce[eq2, x]
(* Abs[a] < 0 && x == 1/Abs[a]^2 *)

Refine[%]
(* False *)
```

The question of course remains: why does Mathematica take the extra step to verify that the condition isn't always `False` in the case of `eq1`?  I don't know.  I just wanted to point out how the result we get is not as outrageous as it seems on first sight.  I do remember a question where `Reduce` wouldn't fully solve a complicated equation unless it was applied multiple time.  So it was clear that it was in principle capable of solving it, yet it wouldn't automatically do so without some nudging, at least when he equation was expressed in certain ways.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I already discovered most of these things (except the MaxExtraConditions option which is awesome to know about). It would not bother me if Mathematica returned no solution sometimes, and a solution with false conditional other times. The thing that bothers me is that it simply returns the solution with no conditional. The `-Abs[a]==Sqrt[x]*Abs[a]` example illustrates this very well. Mathematica returns `x->1` with no conditionals but this is not a valid solution. It is a solution if you consider `Sqrt[x]` as a multivalued function but Mathematica does not do that.

Comment: I really want to understand what the logic branching looks like that allows `x->1` to be returned as a solution. I cannot think of any consistent rules which would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for the difference in the results of `Solve[..]` (cf. `Trace[Solve[..], TraceInternal -> True]`) is that the replacement

```
{x -> 1/Abs[a]^2}
```

makes the first equation `False` but does not make the second `False`:

```
-1 == Sqrt[x]*Abs[a] /. {x -> 1/Abs[a]^2}
(*  False *)

-1/Abs[a] == Sqrt[x] /. {x -> 1/Abs[a]^2}
(*  -(1/Abs[a]) == 1/Abs[a]  *)
```

*Aside*: There is a value you can plug in for `a` to make this last equation evaluate to `True`, and in turn to make `{x -> 1/Abs[a]^2}` into a solution, namely `a = Infinity`.  It's not really a number, though. The question is why doesn't the `Equal[]` evaluate to `False`, and perhaps it's because it is sometimes true (i.e., at least once).

```
Block[{a = Infinity},
 -1/Abs[a] == Sqrt[x] /. {x -> 1/Abs[a]^2}]
(*  True   *)
```

The first equation cannot be solved if `a = Infinity`.  That might be the reason for the difference in the two `Solve[]` results.